# Could not find repos without @EnableJpaRepositories in a proper package structur

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, configuration

I want to use jpa repo in my project. Eventhough repository classes are one level below main configuration class, it just does not find repos. When I added the said annotation, it works. I do not want to add that annotation as I think I have a proper package structure. What may go wrong?

Structure

```
com.springproject.libsec <- AutoConfiguration.java
com.springproject.libsec.repository <- UserRepository.java


@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration    
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.springproject.libsec.repository") // does not work without this
@Import({BeanConfig.class})
public class AutoConfiguration {

}
```

User repo

```
@Repository // with or without @Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, UUID> {

}
```

This is not an executable app but starter lib.

Comment: is your main class or your @SpringApplication in the package com.springproject.libsec?

Comment: I do not have main class. IT is a starter library.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is by default spring-data lookup your repositories under the main class / @SpringApplication package (not sure right now)

So you have to set the package where spring has to lookup because the Main Class / @SpringApplication probably is provided by Spring and it is not in the same or super path package

If you package the project (Sorry I'm a maven boy)

```
mvn clean package
```

You could see the Jar/War generated. Open the file under META-INF/MANIFEST.MF, you will find an entry called Main-Class probably with a value like ***org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher***

That's why you have to set the package of your repositories.